# How should I enter indexed terms? For example, constants $n_k$ for $k\in\{1,\,\ldots,\,N\}$

Tags: summation, core-language, index

How should I enter

$\quad \quad \sum^{N}_{k=0}{f(n_k)}$

into *Mathematica*? More generally, how should I work with the indices?

Take the following as an example. I know how the `Sum` function works, but how to do get it to work with the $n_k$ in $\sum^N_{k=0}n_k$? Here is what I have:

```
Sum[n (ln (1 + e^(ax + y))), {n, 0, N}]
```

Note that the $n_k$ for $k\in{}\{0, 1, ..., N\}$ are unspecified constants (natural numbers if it matters).

I am trying to simplify a similar series.

Comment: When you write `Sum[n (ln (1 + e^(ax + y))), {n, 0, N}]` above, do you intend `Sum[n Log[1 + E^(a x + y)], {n, 0, N}]`. I hope so, because in the first expression `ln`, `ax`, and `e` are ordinary variables with no special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want something more than this but I would start with [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html):

```
Sum[f[Indexed[n, k]], {k, 0, Ν}]
```

[image]

Note that I replaced `N`, a reserved symbol, with `\[CapitalNu]` which looks the same but is free for use.

Comment: Could you mind explaining the new functionality Indexed  a bit more in details. What does it return just formatted text ... Can we assign values to Indexed what is the difference between part and Indexed  etc. It will be very helpful for future users.

Comment: How symbolic vector part functionality (`Indexed`) integrates with other functionalities, like geometric regions is somewhat poorly documented. It can be used like `Minimize[Indexed[p, 1] - Indexed[p, 2], Element[p, Disk[]]]` ... so, in some contexts `Indexed` has quite a specific meaning.